# Mongomapper retrieve specific fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Whenever I use:

```
Collection.where(:user => "Mark").fields(:pets)
```

And pets is an array, I receive followign response:

> [{"cars" : [], "planes" : [], "id" : "529....0005", "pets" : here are
>   pets}]

Two questions:

- how remove the id
- how to get rid of empty arrays - cars[], planes[]
- I want to retrieve only one/ first record

I have also tried mixing this with mongodb commands:

```
Collection.database.collection(:collections).find_one(:query =>{
  :user => "Mark"
},
:fields => {
  :pets => 1,
  :_id => 0
})
```

but this also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Got it:)

```
Collection.first(:user => "Mark").to_json(:only => [:pets])
```